# Gaussian sufficient statistic calculation

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, references, sufficient-statistics

Consider the Gaussian model
$$
Y_i = \beta + \epsilon_i,\, i = 1, \cdots, n,\; \mbox{where}\; \epsilon_i 
\stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2),
$$
parametrized by $\beta$, with known $\sigma$.
The likelihood function admits the factorization
\begin{align*}
L(Y) &= \frac{1}{ (\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}) ^n } e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (\sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \beta)^2)} \\\\
     &= \frac{1}{ (\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}) ^n } e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} ( \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 + n ( \bar{Y} - \beta)^2)}.
\end{align*}

Evidently, by the Halmos-Savage factorization criterion, the sample mean $\bar{Y}$ is a sufficient statistic. (In fact, it is a minimal sufficient statistic.)

The decomposition
\begin{align*}
L(Y) &= \frac{1}{ (\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}) ^n } e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}  \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2} e^{-\frac{1}{2 \frac{\sigma^2}{n} } (\bar{Y} - \beta)^2 }\\\\
     &\equiv h(Y | \bar{Y}) \; g(\bar{Y}|\beta)
\end{align*}
suggests that $\bar{Y}$ is normally distributed with mean $\beta$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, as it should be. So putting
$$
g(\bar{Y}|\beta) = \frac{1}{ (\sqrt{2\pi \frac{ \sigma^2}{n} })  } e^{-\frac{1}{2 \frac{\sigma^2}{n} } (\bar{Y} - \beta)^2}
$$
leads to
$$
h(Y | \bar{Y}) = \frac{1}{ (\sqrt{ \color{red}{ n }  \cdot 2\pi \sigma^2  }) ^{n-1} } e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2}.
$$

**Question**
What is the explanation for the extra factor of $n$ in $\sqrt{ \color{red}{ n }  \cdot 2\pi \sigma^2  }$? One would expect the conditional density $h(Y | \bar{Y})$ to be a degenerate Gaussian---the joint density of $n-1$ i.i.d. Gaussians with variance $\sigma^2$---supported on a $(n-1)$-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. So the normalization factor ought to be $(\sqrt{ 2\pi \sigma^2  })^{n-1}$, at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}\right)^n = \sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2/n} \left(\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}\right)^{n-1}\sqrt{n}$$

So, $$h(Y | \bar{Y}) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ \color{red}{ n }} \cdot (\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2  }) ^{n-1} } e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2}.$$

The common pdf of degenerated normal distribution is

$$\displaystyle f(\mathbf {x} )=\left(\det \nolimits ^{*}(2\pi {\boldsymbol {\Sigma }})\right)^{-{\frac {1}{2}}}\,e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}(\mathbf {x} -{\boldsymbol {\mu }})'{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{+}(\mathbf {x} -{\boldsymbol {\mu }})}$$
where $\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{+}$ is the generalized inverse and det* is the pseudo-determinant.

Comment: So $\Sigma$ here is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of $(1,...,1)'$ (say $\sigma^2 = 1$). Then $\Sigma = \Sigma^+$. The pseudo-determinant of $2 \pi \Sigma$ is $(2 \pi)^{n-1}$. Where does $n$ come from?